# Posing catches vertices on wrong side of child mesh

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I could explain what's wrong, but I think it's better if I show it.
[image: A dull grey cartoonishly proportioned person, with an armature visible beneath.]
[image: The same person from the previous picture. One arm of the armature is bent up, while the other remains in the same position. The arm that should be stationary has instead been severely bent.]
[image: The same person again, but in weight paint mode, with an upper arm bone selected. The weights are only on the correct arm, and no weights appear on the other.]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem is the weights in the vertex groups that are messed up.

If you switch to *Weight Paint* mode and examine the *Vertex Group* section by hovering the mouse over the list and using the arrow up and down keys to scroll through the list then you will see the problem.

[image: weight paint mode]

For example, there are bones like *Bone.10.R*, *Bone.11.R*, and *Bone.15.R* that have weights for both arms. This causes the problem. Also, there are vertex groups like *Bone.017* that have no corresponding bone and are useless.

To fix the weights, open the drop-down menu of the vertex group list and select *Delete All Groups* to get rid of all weights. Then switch to *Object* mode, select the mesh, then the armature, and use *Parent To > With Automatic Weights* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) to calculate the weights. The armature must be the active object, highlighted in orange.

I highly recommend giving the bones and objects proper names (<kbd>F2</kbd>). Also, consider adding a root bone that is the parent of all other bones. It will help you to move the character properly, especially to move it from the spot.

[image: posed character]